Jenkins job hanging on "Stopping part of [job]"
I have a Jenkins job that has been doing nothing for about an hour at this point. In the Console Log, it says the following:
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
Stopping part of [name of the job] #544

This happens just after Jenkins has fetched the Jenkinsfile from the SCM.
The job has been successfully ran multiple times before with no changes to the Jenkinsfile. The agent it is restricted to is running and has available capacity to run it.
There is no multiple instances of the job trying to run on the same agent.
I have tried to restart the job itself, but the new run had the same thing happen to it. I also restarted the computer the agent is running on, but that once again did nothing

Check Jenkins log, maybe it has some clues.

I'm seeing the same. IIRC the last time this happened the only thing which unstuck this was to restart jenkins server.
